# REGEX - Allow Numbers and . - /

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to allow just numeric and (`.-/`)

It should allow something like that:

`011.235673.98923/0001-12`

Comment: Example is bit loose: you should clarify are multiple adjacent `-` or `.` allowed? What if you have leading `/` or `../`, do those get interpreted as references to root or parent directory? And is `.-` an illegal name? etc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The pattern you're looking for, that matches only those strings with numbers, ., -, and /:

```
^[0-9\.\-\/]+$
```

If you have a specific language you're looking to implement this I may be able to help you.

Comment: This works. You don't need to escape the / and . though, just the -.

Comment: This is true. I usually overly escape because of different quirks present in different languages.

Comment: I'm just noticing that too. The order of those characters can change if you need to escapse the - or not. It's pretty lame.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for `^[\d./-]+$`

Comment: I think you have to escape the dash too

Comment: I fixed it. I forgot about the -. =(

Comment: @Tim: Actually I believe it does match `-`. Try it as-is here: http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: @Cam: Before Bill escaped the dash, it served as a range indicator like in `a-z`, only there is no range between `.` and `/` as they are adjacent in ASCII. The site you linked to confirms this, by the way.

Comment: I edited it like crazy. Sorry about that guys. This one absolutely works and doesn't require escaping, though, I'm not sure if I prefer the escaping or not...

Answer (score 2):

to be sure it's in right order and require every part

```
^(\d+)(\.(\d+))*(\/(\d+))*-(\d+)$
```

edit: Forgot to add the / sry

Comment: This does not match the provided sample.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[\d./-]*$
```

does this. What regex flavor are you using? Perhaps it needs to be adjusted for it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

`(\d|\.|\-|\/)*`

Does it matter how many `-` and `.` and `/` you get? Does the order matter?

Comment: This is much less efficient than a character class.

Comment: Ok that may be so, but it offers variety ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this item

```
[^1-9]
```

To view its performance, refer to the following link
[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mLFc7l/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

```
^[\d\.\-\/]+$
```

If your sequence to be matched isn't at the start of the string, you can skip the `^`. Similarly, `$` is required to match sequence at the end of string.